# A latch is inferred when the assignment conditions are not fully specified. But why does it depend on the level of the clock signal?

Tags: verilog, hardware, register-transfer-level

Take a minimal example:

```
always @*
  if (in) q=d;
```

We know a latch would be inferred. But, since there's no clock signal, why is the latch relying on it? How can we decide which level it is sensitive to?

Answer (score 0):

The latch is not relying on a clock.  In your code, the latch is enabled when the `in` signal is 1.  That means `q` follows the `d` signal.

When `in`=0, `q` does not follow `d`.  `q` retains the previous value it had when `in` transitioned to 0.

[Synthesizable constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Synthesizable_constructs) has a good description also; see the *Transparent latch example*.